# First countable space and convergent sequences

Tags: general-topology, first-countable

Let $(\mathbb{R},T)$ be the co countable topological space where $T=\{A \subseteq \mathbb{R}:A^c 
 \, \text{is countable} \}\cup\{\phi\}$. Take $A=\mathbb{R}/\{1\}$, then

1. $\bar{A}=\mathbb{R}$
2. The space is not first countable.
3. There is no sequence in $A$ that converges to $1$.

My lecture notes only prove the third point while mentioning that the first and second are easy to prove. Is there a way to show why these are true?

Comment: A small search for 'cocountable first countable' already has [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2420813/4280) as its first hit.

Comment: SO not an exact duplicate, but do better reseacrhing your question first...

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it does not demonstrate sufficient effort in searching for existing answers.